# Quicker Way to Create Named Tuple Values

Tags: typescript, tuples

Internally I use a type-id system, which correlates numbers to different types. These are represented by `TypeId<T>`. I have a function factory `foo` that needs to take in these `TypeIds` and return a function that has the corresponding types as parameters:

```js
function foo<T extends any[]>(...T): (...args: ExtractTypeId<T>) => void {...}
```

This works well and it can be used as follows:

```
let aRef: TypeId<string> = getTypeId();
let bRef: TypeId<number> = getTypeId();
 
const bar = foo(aRef, bRef); // (args_0: string, args_1: number) => void
```

However, the code is hard to follow when the parameter names become `args_n`. This can be overcome by using a named tuple, but it requires a lot of duplicated code:

```
const bar = foo(...[aRef, bRef] as [a: typeof aRef, b: typeof bRef]);
// bar = (a: string, b: number) => void
```

It only gets harder to follow as more items are added to the function call, and it seems to be because you can only name tuples when they are types.

I tried:

```
foo(...[a: refToA, b: refToB])
```

but that is a syntax error and isn't supported.

Is there a shortcut syntax? Or can I write a method that does most of the inference (`NamedTup(keys, vals)` or similar)?

Comment: Could you [edit] the code here to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue?  Please consider copying and pasting your example code into a standalone IDE like [the TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/we8xXW) and resolve any problems (except of course the problem you're asking about) and then paste the result as plaintext back here.  That will let us get to work on the issue immediately. Good luck!